# Disprove A − C = B − C and A ∩ C = B ∩ C

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm trying to disprove both and so far I was able to disprove part b as shown

`A. If A − C = B − C then A = B
       A = 
       B = 
       C = 
B.  If A ∩ C = B ∩ C then A = B
       A = {1,2,3}
       B = {1,2,3,4}
       C = {1}
With the def of ∩, A ∩ C share and element 1 as for B ∩ C also share a element of 1 but A does not equal B.`

I'm stuck on finding an example to disprove A, or would it be easier to disprove it by using definitions and logical equivalences?

Comment: let $c=\{4\}$ and use $A,B$ from case B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that you only need to come up with a counter example to disprove a statement. You can modify the sets you have in part b for part a. Just let $$ B= \{2,3 \}$$

Comment: so from my understanding, if C has an element that is not in B, it is still left with 

B = {2, 3} for B - C

Comment: Correct, if B and C do not share any elements then B-C = B

Answer (score 0):

One of $A$ or $B$ could contain more points of $C$ than the other.. After removal of those they could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let RED=A, ORANGE=B, CYAN=C.

Then:

[image: set counterexamples]

The first fails case A, the second fails case B.